# c++ language oops

Tags: c++, constructor

Why do we declare constructor's as `public`?

Comment: i can't see why this should be closed - it's a very simple and basic question, but it is a question related to programming that definitely has a specific answer.

Comment: oezi / agreed. these days on stackoverflow getting too picky..

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are the way objects are created. If your constructor were not public, then it couldn't be used to construct a new object from outside the class.

Note that sometimes a non-public constructor is useful, for example:

```
class foo
{
public:
    static foo make_foo(int i)
    {
        // only functions of foo can use that constructor,
        // because it's private; return a foo
        return foo(i);
    }

private:
    foo(int i) { /* construct */ }
};
```

Now `foo` can only be created via the function `make_foo`, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

In the below code line, initialization should take place via constructor. If the constructor is `private` in this case, how is it going to be accessed outside the class scope. Moreover, `foo::foo(int num)` is going to be called by default while instantiation of `obj`.

```
foo *obj = new foo(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't you will not be able to construct the object from other objects.

Comment: Not needed.  You could have a private or protected constructor and a public static method (or friend function) that returns copies of the object.